# Is it OK to omit the "there was" in the following sentence without changing its meaning?

Tags: sentence

> Never in her life had she seen such shocking footage, not to mention two in one day. The experience had shaken her like nothing before. **But there was
>   something else in them that had disturbed her.** Something that still
>   lingered in her mind, like the afterimage of a picture she had overlooked.

I thought of omitting the "there was" in the sentence above:

> But something else in them had disturbed her.

Is that grammatically correct? Does the meaning change?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Proof reading is however off topic here

Comment: Yes. No. Short answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The longer version emphasises the presence of ‘something else’. The shorter version emphasises her being disturbed.